# "iOS 6.0 Simulator" not visible/installable in Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5, osx-mavericks, ios6.0

Today I did a clean install of Mavericks (10.9.1) on my Mac. After that, I installed Xcode 5.0.2 from the Mac App Store. When Xcode was done installing, I opened *Preferences > Downloads* to install the extra components and documentation. Strangely, iOS 6.0 Simulator was not listed there:

[image: "Preferences > Downloads" in Xcode]

When running iOS Simulator, I can only choose to run 7.0.3 or 6.1, so 6.0 is really not yet installed. A week ago I installed Xcode on another Mac (also running Mavericks); at that time it was no problem to install the iOS 6.0 Simulator using the same method.

I have already tried removing the `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/` folder, which appears to hold the cached downloads and metadata. However, this had no effect. And of course I've hit the “Check and Install Now” button several times and also restarted Xcode  a few times, all without effect.

Does anybody have an idea how I can install the iOS 6.0 Simulator?

Comment: I'm running Mavericks and I can't see anything below iOS 6.1 available for download, either.  It may be that running Xcode under 10.8 would be what is needed to allow downloading iOS 6.0 & 5.0 simulators.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann The other Mac I mentioned in my question was also running Mavericks, so that would be an improbable cause. Maybe it has something to do with the hardware (CPU)? My current Mac is pretty new (Early 2013 Retina MacBook Pro), while the other Mac was older (2010 MacBook Pro or something).

Comment: My Mac is "really old" and I see only 7.0 and 6.1. But really, I do not see the point of installing 6.0, since anyone whose device can run 6.0 would update to 6.1. m.

Comment: @matt Thanks! That's interesting; maybe Apple stopped offering the 6.0 simulator in the past few days?

Comment: Very possible. I am pretty sure that Apple "phones home" in order to populate this list. So maybe this is a change at the server end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple replied to the radar I filed. Apparently the iOS 6.0 simulator is not compatible with Mavericks.