# Yosemite ios 6.1 simulator can not launch?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, osx-yosemite

I use the Yosemite Xcode 5.1.1 to test my project ,in 7.1 simulator is ok ,but can not test it in 6.1.1 simulator ,  every time show a alert ios simulator failed to install the application. even reset the simulator , can not launch. anyone can help me solve it ?

Comment: i guess you have to wait some more for apple final release of yosemite.Its still in beta.Thanks

Comment: Xcode 5.1.1 isn't supported under Yosemite, is it?

Comment: you should check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901287/in-os-x-10-10-yosemite-beta-how-do-i-test-using-ios-6-1-simulator

Comment: Yes, it seems that Yosemite will not support IOS 6. just like swift doesn't support IOS 6. if my want to improve for ios6,the only way is use OS below Yosemite. Thanks all guys.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you -

Go to Xcode Option -

First delete all simulators.
Windows-> Devices-> then a window will open. At left bottom corner of this window you will get -(minus) button. Click at there and delete All  Simulators.

Then add simulators -
Windows-> Devices-> then a window will open. At left bottom corner of this window you will get +(plus) button. Click at there and add All  Simulator.

and then Restart Xcode and Simulator and try.

Comment: I downvoted this answer. I'm sure you didn't try this on Yosemite, because iOS 6 simulator won't work on Yosemite. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26647141/131160

Comment: Ok Sorry for that, There might be possibility that my issues many be different from yours. and i understood same, Sorry :)