# Xcode 5.1.1 - iOS 6.1 Simulator not responding

Tags: xcode, ios6, simulator, xcode5.1.1

I need to test an application on an iOS6 simulator. Since this iOS version is not part of the current Xcode6 environment, I tried to install Xcode 5.1.1 beside my Xcode 6 installation and use it.

I downloaded Xcode 5.1.1 from the Apple developer pages and installed in in my applications folder. After launch I am downloading and installing the iOS 6.1 SDK from within Xcode.

After that I am trying to launch the simulator (NOT with an app, just a clean launch) but when the simulator window is shown it keeps black. The log says:

> Could not lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.host_support: 1102

repeatingly. Clicking "Reset Content and Settings..." wont work. I also deleted the SDK file from

> ~/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/

and the 6.1 Folder from

> ~/Users/*username*/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/

And made a fresh install. Also no effect. I know there are a lot of similar questions here on stack, but they all suggest the "Reset Content and Settings..." which wont work for me. Any idea what might going on?

When launching an iOS7.1 simulator from Xcode 5.1.1 it starts up and works like a charm. The iOS7.1 comes with the Xcode bundle, the iOS6.1 simulator has to be installed manually. Maybe that's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of adding extra information as a comment, you should just edit your question. Keeps everything clean. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

i probably found the answer here: [In OS X 10.10 (Yosemite Beta), How do I Test Using iOS 6.1 Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901287/in-os-x-10-10-yosemite-beta-how-do-i-test-using-ios-6-1-simulator)

In short: iOS6 is not supported under OS-X 10.10 and so the simulator won't work.

Comment: Yes, versions of the iOS Simulator runtime prior to 7.1 are not supported in Yosemite.  Your best bet is to grab VMWare or setup multiple partitions and keep a Mavericks + Xcode 5.1 install there for iOS 6 testing.